# Node JS add children properties to JSON

Tags: node.js, arrays, json

I have 2 Json ARRAY `listA` and `listB` want to add `listB` items into `listA` based on id's `issue_id` and `descendents_parent_issue_id`

```
const listA = [
  {
    "issue_id": 2,
    "name": 'A',
  },
  {
    "issue_id": 1,
    "name": 'B',
  },
  {
    "issue_id": 3,
    "name": 'C'
  },
  {
    "issue_id": 4,
    "name": 'D',
  }
];

const listB = [{
    "descendents_issue_id": 7,
    "descendents_parent_issue_id": 2,
    "issue": "Breakdown",
  },{
    "descendents_issue_id": 881,
    "descendents_parent_issue_id": 7,
    "issue": "Hydraulic arm failure"
  },{ 
    "descendents_issue_id": 8,
    "descendents_parent_issue_id": 2,
    "descendents_issue": "Setup/ Changeover"
  },{
    "descendents_issue_id": 942,
    "descendents_parent_issue_id": 7,
    "descendents_issue": "Pump Overload"
  }];
```

`Expected output:`

```
 [
    {
        "issue_id": 2,
        "name": "A",
        "children": [
            {
                "descendents_issue_id": 7,
                "descendents_parent_issue_id": 2,
                "issue": "Breakdown",
                "children": [
                  {
                      "descendents_issue_id": 881,
                      "descendents_parent_issue_id": 7,
                      "issue": "Hydraulic arm failure"
                  },
                  {
                      "descendents_issue_id": 942,
                      "descendents_parent_issue_id": 7,
                      "descendents_issue": "Pump Overload"
                  }
                ]
            },
            { 
              "descendents_issue_id": 8,
              "descendents_parent_issue_id": 2,
              "descendents_issue": "Setup/ Changeover"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "issue_id": 1,
        "name": "B"
    },
    {
        "issue_id": 3,
        "name": "C"
    },
    {
        "issue_id": 4,
        "name": "D"
    }
]
```

tried this following code not getting the expected output

```
  function processIssues(arr, arrayB) {
  return arr.reduce((result, item) => {
    const itemInB = arrayB.find(itemB => itemB.descendents_parent_issue_id == item.issue_id);
    if (itemInB) { 
      let child = [];
      child.push(itemInB);
      item.children = child
    }    

    return [...result, item];
  }, []);
}
```

`Getting Output`

```
[
    {
        "issue_id": 2,
        "name": "A",
        "children": [
            {
                "descendents_issue_id": 7,
                "descendents_parent_issue_id": 2,
                "issue": "Breakdown"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "issue_id": 1,
        "name": "B"
    },
    {
        "issue_id": 3,
        "name": "C"
    },
    {
        "issue_id": 4,
        "name": "D"
    }
]
```

when I tried recursion  getting maximum call stack exceeded. please help

Answer (score 0):

I think you should parse the items for the first array and try to scan the second array matching items with `issue_id`:

```js
const processIssues = (arr, arrB) => {
    let found;
    return arr.map(({ issue_id, children = [], ...rest }) => {
        found = arrB.find(
            ({ descendents_parent_issue_id }) =>
                descendents_parent_issue_id === issue_id
        );
        return found
            ? { issue_id, children: [...children, { ...found }], ...rest }
            : { issue_id, ...rest };
    });
};
```